# Angular2 single ngFor for multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, ngfor

Is it possible to use multiple array's for ngFor in Angular?

```
   *ngFor="let device of element.devices && element.zones.devices"// something like this

export interface Element {
    id: string;
    name: string;   
    zones: Zone[];
    devices: Device[];
}

export class Zone {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    devices: Device[];
}

export class Device {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

I'll be having access to Element object, from that I need to display all the devices and devices inside zones.

Comment: Those [expressions](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions) are similar to JavaScript; what would you expect from `arr1 && arr2.devices `?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated my question

Answer (score 5):

Use `concat` to concatenate two arrays and then use `ngFor` over it

```
*ngFor = "let device of arr1.concat(arr2.devices)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two arrays as below

```
this.elements= arr1.concat(arr2);
```

In addition, to avoid the `undefined` error you should be using **?** type safe operator as below

```
<div *ngFor="let device of elements?.devices">
    <span> {{device?.name}} </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the list elements change after I did concat? How can I handle that scenario?

Comment: by change what do you exactly mean

Comment: "Element" i'm getting as @Input. user can add devices to this element or can add zones which contains devices again. I need to combine both devices(independent) and devices which are inside zones and display in html. If user add's or deletes devices then list should update.

Comment: @PratapA.K if you concat all the devices into one variable, lets call it devices, then iterate over that *ngFor="let device of devices" then change detection will run of new devices are added or removed.